# How to rigorously prove this limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I would like to prove that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k-e^{-\lambda\frac{k}{n}}\right)=0$$
where $f$ is a continuously differentiable and bounded function from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
So far, I have written the following:
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k-e^{-\lambda\frac{k}{n}}\right)\right|\leq\frac{\|f\|}{n}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(e^{-\lambda\frac{k}{n}}-\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k\right)$$
Then, I have used the fact that:
$$e^{-\frac{\lambda}{n}}=1-\frac{\lambda}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
And then:
$$e^{-\frac{k\lambda}{n}}=\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)^k$$
But at this stage I am not sure how to rigorously treat the big O term in order to conclude. Any ideas or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing your strategy is to try to bound the entire infinite sum by some function of $n$ that grows less quickly than $n$?

Comment: Could you split the infinite sum into two and then use the term for a geometric series?

Comment: Ideally I would want to bound the absolute value above by $\frac{\|f\|}{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} O\left(\frac{1}{n^{k+j}}\right)$, but I need to determine $j$

Comment: thanks I will try this also

Comment: The $k$ ranges over $0$ to $n$ or $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: I tried the geometric series attack, but I got a term linear in $n$ on the inside of the brackets. Maybe @Zhanxiong is right- maybe the continuous differentiability condition is important?

Comment: The differentiability condition is not relevant here as this is part of a wider problem, sorry should have just said continuous and bounded

Comment: With the geometric series, I get that the sum of the difference is equal to $\frac{1}{\frac{\lambda}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}-\frac{n}{\lambda}$, can we conclude with this?

Comment: ...actually I don't think the infinite geometric series idea is good at all... I'm either summing wrong, or I'm getting an infinite term. Anyway- looks like your way worked :)

Comment: @Zhanxiong, the $k$ ranges from $0$ to infinity

Comment: Here is what I got: $\frac{1}{1 - e^{-\frac{\lambda}{n}}} - \frac{n}{\lambda}$. I don't know if you can show that that term grows slower than $n$ though...

Comment: @ColmBhandal yes this is same as mine, except I just expanded the exponential in the denominator

Comment: Good to get same result. But I'm stuck from here! I guess the below answer is the best approach.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, is it correct to say that $\frac{1}{\lambda+O(\frac{1}{n})}-\frac{1}{\lambda}$ converges to zero as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Yes, this correct. And I believe this is the correct way to attack the problem.

Comment: @Zhanxiong thanks man

Comment: On more detail needs to be verified: $e^{-kx} > (1 - x)^k$ for $x \in (0, 1)$ for all $k$ so that the absolute symbol can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just expand binormally. For $k\leqslant n$
\begin{align}
e^{-\frac{k\lambda}{n}}&=\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)^k
\\
&=\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k+k\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{k-1}O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\\
&=\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k+k\left(1-\frac{(k-1)\lambda}{n}\right)O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\\
&=\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k+k \:O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
for $\left(1-\frac{(k-1)\lambda}{n}\right)=O(1)$.
So 
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\leqslant n} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k-e^{-\lambda\frac{k}{n}}\right)\right|&\leqslant \frac{\|f\|}{n}\sum_{k\leqslant n}\left(e^{-\lambda\frac{k}{n}}-\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k\right)
\\
&\leqslant \frac{\|f\|}{n}O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\sum_{k\leqslant n}k
\\
&=\|f\|O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\to0
\end{align}

Comment: ok this is what I was trying to get, thanks @hermes

Comment: Is it OK? You are summing $k$, not $n$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, do you mean we cannot say that $\sum_{k\geq 0}O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ goes to zero?

Comment: Yes, because you must do the summation first. And I felt that the condition of $f$ is not fully used (for instance, differentiability).

Comment: @hermes, is it obvious to say that $\sum_{k\geq 0}O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ goes to zero?

Comment: I modify the proof.

Comment: The OP said $k$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$, so your last step is problematic.

Comment: @hermes, isn't $\sum_{k\geq0} 1$ equal to infinity?

Comment: $k$ can't be infinity. It must be $k<n$, otherwise $f(\frac{k}{n})$ would be unbounded.

Comment: @hermes It was assumed $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: But $\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k$ could be unbounded

Comment: Normally it is considered as Riemann integral. If k go to infinity, it is a double limit problem, but inner sum for k may not exist. So k must be less than something, mostly n.

Comment: I modify the proof.